# use flatmap on javascript, with condition

Tags: javascript, lodash, flatmap

I am creating a component which handles watch and edit permissions.
The data structure I use to hold the permissions looks like this:

```
const input = [{
    isAllowed: true,
    permissionType: "watch",
    userId: 14
  },
  {
    isAllowed: false,
    permissionType: "edit",
    userId: 14
  },
  {
    isAllowed: true,
    permissionType: "edit",
    userId: 24
  },
  {
    isAllowed: false,
    permissionType: "edit",
    userId: 34
  },
  {
    isAllowed: false,
    permissionType: "watch",
    userId: 44
  },
  {
    isAllowed: false,
    permissionType: "edit",
    userId: 44
  }
]
```

At first, I just wanted to get a list of all users with any permissions given at all, so I would use

```
let managers = _.flatMap(props.settings.managerPermissions, (p) => p.userId);
managers = [...new Set(managers)];
```

So this would leave me with `managers = [14,24,34,44]`, but I need to edit this flatmap in a way that I would not get back the id of a manager which has no permissions at all, even if they were added to the list already, so in this case the return value of the new flatmap should be `managers = [14,24]`. (ofcourse flatMap is not a must here and if there's a better way to do it I would be happy to see it)

Comment: what does it '*no permissions at all,*' mean in this case? why `14` and `24`?

Comment: @NinaScholz I mean managers who were on the list but every occurrence is false.
14 is there because it has permission to view, and 24 is there because it has permissions to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need flatMap when the result of map would be an array of arrays, and you want a flat array.

In this case filter the array by `isAllowed` and then map to `userId`:

```js
const arr = [{"isAllowed":true,"permissionType":"watch","userId":14},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"edit","userId":14},{"isAllowed":true,"permissionType":"edit","userId":24},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"edit","userId":34},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"watch","userId":44},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"edit","userId":44}]

const managers = [...new Set(
  arr
  .filter(o => o.isAllowed)
  .map(o => o.userId)
)]

console.log(managers)
```

However, you can actually use `Array.flatMap()` (or lodash equivalent) to map and filter at the same time. It's less idiomatic the map/filter combo, and I'm not sure about the performance, so I don't use it myself. The idea is to return an empty array for items that you don't want:

```js
const arr = [{"isAllowed":true,"permissionType":"watch","userId":14},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"edit","userId":14},{"isAllowed":true,"permissionType":"edit","userId":24},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"edit","userId":34},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"watch","userId":44},{"isAllowed":false,"permissionType":"edit","userId":44}]

const managers = [...new Set(
  arr.flatMap(o => o.isAllowed ? o.userId : [])
)]

console.log(managers)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just filter out the `isAllowed=false` and then do the same - although `flatMap` seems to be useless (as there is no nesting of arrays) - just use `map`

```js
const input = [
 {isAllowed: true,
  permissionType: "watch",
  userId : 14
 },
 {isAllowed: false,
  permissionType: "edit",
  userId : 14
 },
 {isAllowed: true,
  permissionType: "edit",
  userId : 24
 },
 {isAllowed: false,
  permissionType: "edit",
  userId : 34
 },
 {isAllowed: false,
  permissionType: "watch",
  userId : 44
 },
 {isAllowed: false,
  permissionType: "edit",
  userId : 44
 }]
 
 const managers = [...new Set(input.filter(x => x.isAllowed).map(x => x.userId))];
 console.log(managers);
```

Comment: `x.isAllowed == true` really?

Comment: @NinaScholz lol - silly. fingers going faster than brain

Comment: `x.isAllowed === true` could actually be useful here, in case the data is corrupted (for example with boolean strings), so it assumes no permission by default.